# Swipe up to remove an image from gridview using android

Tags: android, listener, swipe

I wanna remove an image from gridview by swiping up(Not dragging). I have an activity like this.From this i wanna remove an image by swip over the image. 
[image]

I tried the following code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
    final List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    Log.i("Size", "Size=" + aList.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hm.put("txt", "Country : " + food[i]);
        hm.put("cur", "Currency : " + currency[i]);
        hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]));
        aList.add(hm);
    }
    String[] from = {"flag", "txt", "cur"};
    int[] to = {R.id.flag};
    final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.recyclerview_item, from, to);
    final GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
    final int[] pos = new int[1];
    gridview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Removed" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            Log.i("Data", "data=" + data);
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            Log.i("X2", "X2=" + x2);
            Log.i("Flag2", "Flag2=" + flag2);
            pos[0] = position;
            gridview.setOnDragListener(new AdapterView.OnDragListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                    try {
                        aList.remove(position);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                        Log.i("Exception", "Excep=" + e);
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

Can anyone help me to do the task.

Comment: you can do it with **recycler-view** here is a real project [**LINK**](https://github.com/nemanja-kovacevic/recycler-view-swipe-to-delete)

Comment: Thank you @HamidReza , The above mentioned project working fine but that is not my requirement. I wanna delete an item by swiping bottom to up and i need to use gridview , not recycler-view.

Comment: recycler-view is much more better than list-view and grid-view in **performance** and **flexibility**, so try it.for swiping bottom to up there is a flag you can change it from right to left to any other directions.